# Как замедлить кручение объекта по своей оси в Box2D?

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, box2d

Квадрат падает под углом, отскакивая от земли он крутится, но крутится бесконечно, а нужно что бы его кручение замедлялось, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Для замедления движения тела в отсутствии контакта с другими телами предусмотрено демпфирование (Damping). Оно бывает линейное и угловое - то, что нужно в данном случае. Его можно задать при создании тела:

```
bodyDef.angularDamping = 0.01f;
```

Comment: Благодарю. А то сам не мог найти.